# Eight-disk RAID-Z2 array has less capacity available than expected

Tags: debian, software-raid, zfs, raid-z

I have a problem to explain the missing capacity in my raidz2

```
# zpool status -v nas
  pool: nas
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        nas         ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdh     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors


# zpool list nas
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
nas   21.8T  6.11G  21.7T         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -


# zfs list nas
NAME   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
nas   4.34G  15.0T  4.34G  /nas
```

I uses 8x3TB (2,72TiB). The physical size is ~21,8TiB, thats okey. But the available space is 15,0TiB, but i expect 16,3 TiB.

I know the raidz use some additional space for metadata (1/64), but thes does not explain a gap of 1,3 TiB.

Ary they any other explanations or checks I can perform to find the culprit for the gap?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1:

```
zfs list -t all
NAME   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
nas   4.34G  15.0T  4.34G  /nas
```

EDIT2: 
It seem to be connected with the ashift. I tried to create a zpool with ashift=9 and here is the result:

```
# zfs list
NAME   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
nas   99.9K  15.8T  35.9K  /nas
# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
nas   21.8T   152K  21.7T         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Recover 0,8 TiB, but still a loss of 0,5 TiB. Additional the write performance decrease.

**Solution**:
First thanks for your information.
For myself I do not found the right solution but i decided to use my raidz with ashift=12 (4k) for better performance and lower capacity. By the way I also think it's not a bad discussion to use the real physical sector size of the harddisk.

Comment: Please check with `zfs list -t all` that there are no snapshot or whatever. // Oh, and by the way: That RAIDZ2 is way too large. It’ll have incredibly slow resilver durations. [Please read this.](http://jrs-s.net/2015/02/06/zfs-you-should-use-mirror-vdevs-not-raidz/)

Comment: I'm not familiar with raid systems or the raid configuration. But the output for `zfs list -t all`  seems to show no snapshots. 
So long the resilver duration does not take days, these isn't a big disadvantage. Because RAID-Z2 can tollerate the loss of two drives, I think longer resilver times seem like a reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: But it *will* take days, and that’s only when defaults are tweaked to prioritize rebuilding over regular I/O and as little I/O as possible occurs. Also, you probably bought all disks of one type all at once, so if one fails, others are *very* likely to fail too. But well, it’s your data. `ashift=9` is a super-bad idea on 4K drives.

Comment: Where do you take the information about a duration of days? See [Link](http://louwrentius.com/zfs-resilver-performance-of-various-raid-schemas.html). Based on these it will take hours, but not days. And if its so obvious a bad decisions to take a raidz, why it's so popular. I mean we are not talking about apple guys, we talking about administrator for linux.

Comment: Why is ashift 9 a super-bad idea? See [Link] (http://louwrentius.com/zfs-performance-and-capacity-impact-of-ashift9-on-4k-sector-drives.html). It seems to be a decision what seems to be more important for the usage, space or performance. Both are possible traceable options. 
For my self I`m far away from being an expert, so i'm depend on others   explanations and argumentation's. at these point, i'm sorry i have just overfly your link (have not jet the time to read and understand), but only a super-bad idea is an argument without expression.

Comment: By the way I am grateful for your help to understand these topic better. And each hint or exchange of argumentations helps a lot.

Comment: The rebuild times are my own experience with a tweaked(!) 80% full 6×3 TB RAIDZ2 with `ashift=9` (most likely reduces rebuild performance a lot).

Comment: @SimonA `ashift=9` with 4K-native drives is a bad idea because it hugely increases the risk that the drive must do a read-modify-write cycle, which will kill your I/O performance (as you have observed). The ideal value for `ashift` is whatever maps to the physical sector size of your storage, with higher values being useful in exceptional circumstances.